# Finding the right path for css styling a video

Tags: css

I'm using a video plugin for my wordpress site.

I want to change the width of the videos.

However it seems like I'm not using the correct path for the id, as I'm not seeing any changes from my css styling.

This is the info I have gotten from using the editor in chrome:

[image]
[image]

I want to change the inline styling, so I read I had to use !important to overrule it. But for testing I just used bg-color.
I have tried to access the video with these attempts with no success:

```
.vjs-tech {
background-color: red; 
}

#player_html5_api.vjs-tech {
background-color: red; 
}
#player_html5_api {
background-color: red; 
}

video#player_html5_api {
background-color: red; 
}
```

Comment: I know that my comment can be stupid. But did you clear your cache ?

Comment: Yes I have. And I just did it again to make sure.

Comment: I understand this type of issues, have to deal with this daily, haha. Maybe try this first, `#player_html5_api { width: 20%; }`, if it doesn't work, add an `!important`. From there you can see which class/id can directly affect it.

Comment: @Gosi I already tried that. Its not affecting it at all. Its very strange..

Comment: @Chao1920 Ah ic, hmm do you have the url of that particular page with the video?

Comment: @Gosi Yes, do you have the access to start a chat? I'm not suppose to share the site public.

Comment: Nope, I cant create a chat, we'll need to have a long comments going forth and back for that option to appear for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218200/discussion-between-gosi-and-chao1920).

Answer (score 0):

After a good chat with Gosi, I found the issue to be the video I wanted to be changed had its css located in another folder than the regular wordpress css folder, since it's a plugin. So I had to go in the plugins css folder and make my changes there.